# Expression not working in the view that is set by a service in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-controller, angularjs-controlleras

I'm quite stuck on trying to access the view with an expression that obviously fails to work.  I have a Service:

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).service('myService', function($timeout){
    this.sayHello = function(name) {
        $timeout(function(){
            alert('Hi, I am...' +name);
        }, 3000);
    };
});
```

Controller:

```js
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
.controller('MyController', function(myService) {
    myService.sayHello('AngularJS Service');
});
```

View

```html
<div ng-controller="MyController">{{sayHello}}</div>
```

In the view I have:

```
{{sayHello()}}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The service function is not bound to the controller, so the view doesn't find it.  Do this:

```js
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
.controller('MyController', function(myService) {
    this.sayHello = myService.sayHello;
});
```

To bind to `this` instead of `$scope`, you need `controllerAs` syntax in the view as well, like `as c1`:

```html
<div ng-controller="MyController as c1">
    {{ c1.sayHello() }}
</div>
```

Function bindings in the view will fire repeatedly though.